# Variable change detection actionscript 3.0

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, events, variables, detection

Lets say I have a which can be either 0 (false) or 1 (true). Is there a way to detect when the variable is CHANGING to 1 (true). I want a sound to play whenever it becomes true, but only once.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no built-in mechanism that signals a changed value, but you can easily implement this yourself:  Create a setter function for your variable and have it call the `playSound()` method, whenever the value is set to 1.

```
private var _myVariable : int = 0;

public function set myVariable (n:int) : void
{
    _myVariable = n;
    if (n == 1) playSound();
}
```

You might also want to check out the [Observer pattern](http://www.swinburne.edu.au/design/tutorials/P-flash/T-The-Observer-Design-Pattern-in-Actionscript-3/ID-145/) if you're going to do things like this on a larger scale.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to use a Boolean data type here?

Comment: Depending on where that value comes from, it might not: When you pass in values from XML attributes, for example, there are no actual Boolean values, but only String representations.  It would then be advisable to use "0" and "1" instead of "true" and "false".  That, however, would not change anything about the notification problem.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [`mx.binding.utils.BindingUtils`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/binding/utils/BindingUtils.html)

Comment: BindingUtils is useful for variables prepended with [Bindable] meta tag. It's only used by flex compiler and internally it generates setter and getter for variables marked [Bindable].

Comment: personally i prefer to add event dispatching to variable setters manually in such cases, however `BindingUtils` works fine in .as class files and is the only as3 option for such cases